# Azure SQL database connect to SSIS using OLE DB

Tags: ssis, ado.net, oledb, azure-sql-database

Is there a way of connecting an Azure SQL Server Database to SSIS using OLE DB connection? If yes please indicate what provider to use in the Connection Manager and what is the Authentication method you used.

I could only connect it using an ADO.NET connection, but SSIS can do a lot of things with OLE DB that it can't do with ADO.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provider: Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 11.0.
Authentication method: SQL Server Authentication.

In case you don't know your admin username and password, go to Azure SQL Server and press Overview. You will see under Server Admin your username. Then press Reset Password and enter your new password.

Now go to SSIS and try to connect using this info to Azure SQL Server.

Bottom line here, Azure SQL Server supports OLE DB connection.